# Figures and tables moving to end of file

Tags: floats

I know, a similar question has been asked several times, but as the answers did not fix my issue, I wondered whether I overlooked something in my case. The problem is that I write a document on overleaf and want to include several graphics and tables in my document. They all get pushed to the end of the document with one table or figure on a new page. I understand the concept of floats and that they are allowed to be placed flexibly in the document to get an asthetically pleasing result. I also know that I can influence where they are placed with different parameters. I am aware that different packages, such as placeins and Float, may give me additional options to refrain floats from jumping all over the place. Yet, none of these options have helped me prevent the tables and figures to be placed at the end of the document. I first wondered if the problem was the size of my figures and table. But the issue persists even with one single simple table such as this one which is surrounded by text:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Results}
\begin{tabular}{llrrrrrr}
    \hline
 & Type & Df & t & p & M & SD & Cohen's D \\ 
    \hline
First effect & One-sided & 45 & 9.01 & .000*** & 21.74 & 16.21  & 1.34  \\ 
Second effect & One-sided & 45 & 7.00 & .000*** & 0.38 &  0.36  & 1.03 \\ 
Third effect & Two-sided & 45 & 6.34 & .000*** & 0.34 &  0.37  & 0.93 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\FloatBarrier
```

I tried using the htpb! option and the Float Barrier from the placeins package, as seen above, also the H option of the Float package. None of it helped. May some setting or use of any package influence the placement of the figures? These are all the packages used in the document.

```
\documentclass[stu, donotrepeattitle, 12pt]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx, dcolumn}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\linespread{2}
```

I'm greatful for every hint I get! Thank you all in advance!

Comment: the class forces the floats to the end. Use the `floatsintext` option.

Comment: Welcome! Ulrike has given the answer. To debug this, I would have: made a copy of my file and then stripped the copy down to minimal that demonstrates the problem. Then I would have kept changing the minimal copy to find out where the problem was. In latex, document classes and packages make all the difference, in your case, apa7.

Comment: Thank you very much, the floatsintext option was indeed the problem! I tried the approach of stripping down my document, hence that I made a simple document with only one table. I did not know that the class would push floats to the end. I'm the wiser for it now. Thanks a lot for the comments.